# Search For Different File Name in Loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

I want to do search through a bunch of directories to find missing files. The format of the directories and files is YYYY/MM/file_name_YYYYMMDD.csv. So what I want to do is something like:

```
for date in `list_of_dates.txt`
do
 if [! -f /YYYY/MM/file_name_YYYYMMDD.csv]
   echo $date
 fi
```

What I can't figure out how to do is make each iteration look for the right file in the right directory. Is there a way to do this in a bash script?

Comment: The question is a bit uncertain to me. How do you define a "missing file"? Do you want to list all files that do not follow the pattern you described?

Comment: Dose the file contain only the filenames on the format `file_name_YYYYMMDD.csv` or is there a path as well?

Comment: The `list_of_dates.txt` file, what does it contain?

Comment: `list_of_dates.txt` is a text file that just has a list of strings representing the dates for which I expect there to be a file. A file is "missing" if I expect there to be a file for that date, but can't find a file matching the pattern.

Comment: @GreeTreePython It's difficult to write a solution when the data is unknown. A date can have many many different formats...

Comment: YYYYMMDD e.g. 20170127

Comment: these constructive comments should be edited into the question to help clarify the question

Comment: An important syntax note: `[` is actually a builtin **command**, not mere syntax (at a bash shell, type `help [`). Like any shell command, it requires whitespace to separate it from its arguments. You **require** a space after `[` and a space before `]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for dir in ????/??; do
    year=${dir:0:4}
    month=${dir:5}
    days=$(cal "$month" "$year" | awk 'NF {DAYS = $NF}; END {print DAYS}') 
    for date in seq 1 "$days"; do
        filename="file_name_${year}${month}${date}.csv"
        if [[ ! -f /"$year"/"$month"/"$filename" ]]; then
            echo "$filename is missing."
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: cool +1  or even `days=$(($(cal $mon $year | wc -w) -9))`